# Using GET parameters in Play Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, playframework

I tried to build Web Service Server using Play Framework 1.2.3 and got some problem:

1. I tried this tutorial [How to use play! framework to develop webservice](http://tjureyoung.blogcn.com/articles/how-to-use-play-framework-to-develop-webservice.html). I don't know how to request the web service using GET parameters, how to request the web service using parameters?
2. Is it possible to return the result with GIF file in Play? If yes, can anyone provide an example or link for that (tried to googling it before, but no result)?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the webservice described, it should be quite easy. for example, if you have an action as follows

```
public class Application extends Controller {


    public static void sum(Float num1, Float num2) {
        Float result = num1 * num2;
        render(result);
    }
}
```

and a route of

```
GET /webservices/sum                 Application.sum(format:'xml')
```

then all you need to do is call the service like the following

```
/webservices/sum?num1=10.1&num2=13.5
```

this will execute your action by passing in the required parameters

For your second part of the question. You would use `renderBinary` in your action to return your GIF file.